# SwiftUI - Crash when presenting .sheet in minimal project that includes .toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've run into a weird crash when presenting a sheet under certain conditions.I've been able to reproduce it in a starter project and have had confirmation from multiple people that it crashes on their end as well. The strange thing is, that for some simulators / users, these steps don't crash the app.

I've filed a Bug Report with Apple (FB9064549), but thought I'd ask it here as well.

The steps to reproduce the crash are as follows:

1. Click the "Open Detail View" button
2. Go back
3. Click the "Open Detail View" button again
4. Click the "Present Modal"
5. It will crash

The basic content view has a toolbar with a Menu (or just a normal Text) in it and a NavigationLink to push to a new page. If I comment out the .toolbar, the crash does not happen.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                 NavigationLink(
                     destination: DetailView(),
                     label: {
                         Text("Open Detail View")
                     })
            }
                
                // If you comment this out, it does not crash
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Menu {
                            ForEach(1...5, id: \.self) { index in
                                Button {
                                    print("tap menu item")
                                } label: {
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Menu Item \(index)")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text("Filter")
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The presented DetailView can present a .sheet through a binding item. If I use the FullScreenCover instead, it does not crash.

```
struct DetailView: View {
    @State var modalType: ModalType?
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            modalType = .modalWithTabView
        }, label: {
            Text("Present Modal")
        })
        .sheet(item: $modalType, content: { $0 })
    }
}

enum ModalType: Identifiable, View {
    case modalWithTabView

    var id: String {
        return "modalWithTabView"
    }

    var body: some View {
        switch self {
            case .modalWithTabView:
                ModalWithTabView()
        }
    }
}
```

The sheet that is presented is a basic TabView pagination. If I don't add the PageTabViewStyle style, it does not crash.

```
struct ModalWithTabView: View {
    @State var currentStep = 0
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $currentStep) {
            ForEach (0 ..< 10) { index in
                Text("Page \(index)")
                    .tag(index)
            }
        }
        // If you comment this out, it does not crash
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
    }
}
```

If anyone has any pointers please let me know!

Comment: I'm not sure what your UI is supposed to look like, adding a toolbar to a navigation link seems a bit odd to me, maybe add it to the NavigationView, or wrap the NavigationLink on a stack?

Comment: The .toolbar needs to be inside the NavigationView to work, as a modifier on the content itself. In this case there is only a NavigationLink, which is why it's directly on it. When I wrap the NavigationLink in a VStack, the same thing happens. I've updated my question for clarity.